# Why the multiple SupportMapFragment overlap in different fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I am new to developing Android Google Map , I use the two `SupportMapFragment` in different `Fragment-1` and `Fragment-2` respectively.

First , I add the two fragment to `BackStack`. Before showing the any fragment , I will hide the all fragment first.

I want these two fragment were live at the same times , so I did not use replace or remove any fragment. Forex-sample , when the `fragment2` is hiding , but it still do something at the background.

I open the `Fragment-1` at first and turn to the `Fragment-2` , and then back to the `Fragment-1`. The `Fragment-1` show the overlap like the following picture.

[image]

I have try to hide the one of the `Fragment-2`, but it is not working.

IN MainActivity , I manager my fragment.

In `onCreate()` , I will call following function:

```
public void initStartFragment(){

        fragment1= new Fragment1();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment1)
                .addToBackStack(Fragment1.getClass().getName()).commit();

        fragment2= new Fragment2();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment2)
                .addToBackStack(Fragment2.getClass().getName()).commit();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mManager.beginTransaction();
    hideFragment(mFragmentTransaction);

    if(v.getId() == R.id.dive_learning_btn){

        if (fragment1 == null) {
            fragment1= new Fragment1();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment1)
                    .commit();
        }
        mFragmentTransaction.show(fragment1)
                .commit();

    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.expect_setting_btn){

        if (fragment2== null) {
            fragment2= new Fragment2();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment2)
                    .commit();
        }
        mFragmentTransaction.show(fragment2)
                .commit();

    }
}
```

Before show the fragment, I will hide all fragment first:

```
public void hideFragment(FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //if fragment noy null , hide it.
        if (fragment1 != null) {
            ft.hide(fragment1 );
        }
        if (fragment2 != null) {
            ft.hide(fragment12);
        }
    }
```

I want these two fragment were live at the same times , so I did not use replace or remove any fragment.

Why this condition happened ?  Did I missing something ?

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put your fragment manager code? please

Comment: @DanielCarreto HI , I have edit and add the code of fragment manager.

Comment: Thanks, chance add method to replace in your second fragment, with that you avoid the overlay, and to hide switch with mFragmentTransaction.show(fragment2)
            .commit(); and mFragmentTransaction.hide(fragment2)
            .commit();

Comment: @DanielCarreto But I want these two fragment were live at the same times , so I did not use replace or remove any fragment.

Comment: okay,  just change ft.hide(fragment1 ); with  mFragmentTransaction.hide(fragment2) .commit(); to show/hide fragments

Comment: @DanielCarreto I already hide the all fragment ,before I click the button to show fragment.